# IEEE Access LaTeX: using \textbf{ } in table with multicolumn generates error: Argument \bf has an extra }

Tags: multicolumn, bold, ieeeaccess

Same code is generating table with bold option in other temples

```
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{table*}[h!]
\centering
\caption{table1}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\textbf{Dataset}    & \textbf{Total News}    & \textbf{Fake}         &
```

Error is shown here: Argument \bf has an extra }

```
\multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{Real}}       \\ \hline
\textbf{PolitiFact} & 72                     & 36                    & 
\multicolumn{2}{c|}{36}                  \\ \hline
\textbf{GossipCop}  & 100                    & 50                    & 
\multicolumn{2}{c|}{50}                  \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\textbf{}} & \textbf{Total Tweets} & \textbf{Fake Tweets} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{Real Tweets}} \\ \hline
\textbf{PolitiFact} & 5045                   & 3371                  & 
\multicolumn{2}{c|}{1674}                \\ \hline
\textbf{GossipCop}  & 3636                   & 2489                  & 
\multicolumn{2}{c|}{1147}                \\ \hline
\textbf{}           & \textbf{Total ML Rows} & \textbf{Fake Rows}    & 
\multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{Real Rows}}  \\ \hline
\textbf{PolitiFact} & 4085                   & 2972                  & 
\multicolumn{2}{c|}{1113}                \\ \hline
\textbf{GossipCop}  & 3342                   & 2245                  & 
\multicolumn{2}{c|}{1097}                \\ \hline
\textbf{}           & \textbf{Total Users}   & \textbf{In Fake Only} & 
\textbf{In Real Only} & \textbf{In Both} \\ \hline
\textbf{PolitiFact} & 3865                   & 2763                  & 1081                  & 10               \\ \hline
\textbf{GossipCop}  & 2564                   & 1706                  & 858                   & 8                \\ \hline
\textbf{}           & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}} \textbf{1st Degree}\\\textbf{Fake Followers}\end{tabular}   & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}} 
\textbf{1st Degree}\\\textbf{Fake Followings}\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}} \textbf{1st Degree} \\\textbf{Real Followers}\end{tabular} & 
\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}\textbf{1st Degree}\\\textbf{ Real Followings}\end{tabular} \\ \hline
\textbf{PolitiFact} & 312M                    & 27M                  & 534M                  & 19M               \\ \hline
\textbf{GossipCop}  & 209M                   & 19M                  & 378M                   & 12M                \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Anyway, inside a cell you can as well use `\bfseries`.

Comment: With the information you provided so far, I can't reproduce the error message you get. Therefore, please prepare a complete [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that allows others to reproduce your issue.

Answer (score 5):

The newer version of `ieeeaccess.cls` does a ***very bad*** set of definitions.

Let's see what happens. The class is based on `IEEEtran.cls` that enables the old font commands such as `\bf`. Such (silly) idea allows users to do something like `${\bf x}$`, which has been deprecated for more than 25 years.

So the developer of `ieeeaccess.cls` decided that this is not good, but starts with doing

```
\def\textbf#1{{\bf #1}}
```

for no apparent reason than making a robust command fragile *and* introducing the usage of a deprecated command. Oh, no, says the developer, we *redefine* `\bf`.

Here it is! In all its glory!

```
\AtBeginDocument{%
\gdef\operator@encoding{T1}
\gdef\encodingdefault{T1}
%\def\it{\fontencoding{T1}\selectfont}
\long\def\bf#1{\ifmmode\mathbf{#1}\message{Please use mathbf in math mode instead of bf.}\else\fontencoding{T1}\fontseries{b}\selectfont{#1}\fi}
\long\def\rm#1{\ifmmode\mathrm{#1}\message{Please use mathrm in math mode instead of rm.}\else\fontencoding{T1}\selectfont{#1}\fi}
}
```

Now your error can be easily replicated with a very minimal example, namely

```
\documentclass{ieeeaccess}
\begin{document}
\textbf{}
\end{document}
```

If the developers (rightly) don't want authors to use `\bf` they should simply disable it, not relying on faulty heuristics to “fix” the input.

What's the problem? `\textbf{}` is translated into `{\bf}` and `\bf` wants to find an argument, but the next token is `}`. So TeX is forced to issue the error message

```
! Argument of \bf has an extra }.
```

You can fix the problem in two ways: first one, simple, never use `\textbf{}`, but always have something between the braces. After all,

```
 \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\textbf{}}
```

is a complicated way to say

```
 \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{}
```

which can actually be removed altogether.

Second way: reinstate the *right* definition of `\textbf` by saying

```
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textbf}{\bfseries}
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textit}{\itshape}
```

in the document preamble. I also added `\textit`, which is treated similarly in the class. You might also want to do

```
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \let\bf\undefined
  \let\it\undefined
  \let\rm\undefined
}
```

so you will get a better error message in case you use code sent to you by a coauthor who's not aware that the command have been deprecated for a quarter of a century.

---

Note: one could find that the initial statement in this answer is too harsh. Actually, I find it even too gentle.

Comment: I have to admit: I always use `{\em }` and `{\bf }`, both because the command names are shorter and because having the command name inside the block allows the formatted block to be delineated by `{...}`, without any markup preceding or following the brackets. I find the combination of the factors makes text far easier to read uninterrupted in the TeX source. Hence I appreciate what IEEE was trying to do here, even if they botched the implementation badly.

Comment: @COTO You shouldn't. There are several reasons why the two-letter font changing commands have been deprecated.

Answer (score 2):

The class `ieeeaccess` redefines `\textbf` by:

`\def\textbf#1{{\bf #1}}`

That's strange since `\bf` is deprecated in LaTeX. One should use `\bfseries`.

You can put the following line at the end of your preamble.

`\def\textbf#1{{\bfseries #1}}`

With that line, there is no error.

```
\documentclass{ieeeaccess}
\usepackage{graphicx} %<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< needed for ieeeaccess
\usepackage{multirow}

\def\textbf#1{{\bfseries #1}}

\begin{document}

    \begin{table}[h!]
        \centering
        \caption{table1}
        \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
            \hline
    \textbf{Dataset}    & \textbf{Total News}    & \textbf{Fake}         &
    \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{Real}}       \\ \hline
    \textbf{PolitiFact} & 72                     & 36                    & 
    \multicolumn{2}{c|}{36}                  \\ \hline
    \textbf{GossipCop}  & 100                    & 50                    & 
    \multicolumn{2}{c|}{50}                  \\ \hline
    \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\textbf{}} & \textbf{Total Tweets} & \textbf{Fake Tweets} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{Real Tweets}} \\ \hline
    \textbf{PolitiFact} & 5045                   & 3371                  & 
    \multicolumn{2}{c|}{1674}                \\ \hline
    \textbf{GossipCop}  & 3636                   & 2489                  & 
    \multicolumn{2}{c|}{1147}                \\ \hline
    \textbf{}           & \textbf{Total ML Rows} & \textbf{Fake Rows}    & 
    \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{Real Rows}}  \\ \hline
    \textbf{PolitiFact} & 4085                   & 2972                  & 
    \multicolumn{2}{c|}{1113}                \\ \hline
    \textbf{GossipCop}  & 3342                   & 2245                  & 
    \multicolumn{2}{c|}{1097}                \\ \hline
    \textbf{}           & \textbf{Total Users}   & \textbf{In Fake Only} & 
    \textbf{In Real Only} & \textbf{In Both} \\ \hline
    \textbf{PolitiFact} & 3865                   & 2763                  & 1081                  & 10               \\ \hline
    \textbf{GossipCop}  & 2564                   & 1706                  & 858                   & 8                \\ \hline
    \textbf{}           & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}} \textbf{1st Degree}\\\textbf{Fake Followers}\end{tabular}   & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}} 
        \textbf{1st Degree}\\\textbf{Fake Followings}\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}} \textbf{1st Degree} \\\textbf{Real Followers}\end{tabular} & 
    \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}\textbf{1st Degree}\\\textbf{ Real Followings}\end{tabular} \\ \hline
    \textbf{PolitiFact} & 312M                   & 27M                  & 534M                   & 19M               \\ \hline
    \textbf{GossipCop}  & 209M                   & 19M                  & 378M                   & 12M                \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table} 

\EOD  %<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< needed for ieeeaccess

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]

However, a table in the spirit of `booktabs` would probably be more legible...

Comment: I'd prefer to do the right way, namely `\let\textbf\relax\DeclareTextCommand{\textbf}{\bfseries}`. Also `\textit` needs a similar treatment. Anyway, I get no error even without reinstating the right definitions. Indeed the class does, at begin document, `\def\bf{\fontencoding{T1}\fontseries{b}\selectfont}`, so the dubious definition of `\textbf` is definitely not the culprit.

Comment: @egreg. In my version of `ieeeaccess.cls` (just download on `https://template-selector.ieee.org/secure/templateSelector/publicationType`), I have not `def\bf{\fontencoding{T1}\fontseries{b}\selectfont` but `\long\def\bf#1{\ifmmode\mathbf{#1}\message{Please use mathbf in math mode instead of bf.}\else\fontencoding{T1}\fontseries{b}\selectfont{#1}\fi}`...

Comment: Wow! They succeeded to make the thing even worse! Anyway, the right way to proceed is with `\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textbf}{\bfseries}`.

Answer (score 1):

Your posted table compiles fine using the `ieeeaccess` class, as long as you remember to add  `\EOD` before `\end {document}`

The following four files should be in the working directory:

```
ieeeaccess.cls    
IEEEtran.cls    
bullet.png    
notaglinelogo.png
```

[image: a]

```
% !TeX TS-program = pdflatex

\documentclass{ieeeaccess}
\usepackage{graphicx} %<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< needed for ieeeaccess
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[h!]
        \centering
        \caption{table1}
        \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
            \hline
    \textbf{Dataset}    & \textbf{Total News}    & \textbf{Fake}         &
    \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{Real}}       \\ \hline
    \textbf{PolitiFact} & 72                     & 36                    & 
    \multicolumn{2}{c|}{36}                  \\ \hline
    \textbf{GossipCop}  & 100                    & 50                    & 
    \multicolumn{2}{c|}{50}                  \\ \hline
    \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\textbf{}} & \textbf{Total Tweets} & \textbf{Fake Tweets} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{Real Tweets}} \\ \hline
    \textbf{PolitiFact} & 5045                   & 3371                  & 
    \multicolumn{2}{c|}{1674}                \\ \hline
    \textbf{GossipCop}  & 3636                   & 2489                  & 
    \multicolumn{2}{c|}{1147}                \\ \hline
    \textbf{}           & \textbf{Total ML Rows} & \textbf{Fake Rows}    & 
    \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{Real Rows}}  \\ \hline
    \textbf{PolitiFact} & 4085                   & 2972                  & 
    \multicolumn{2}{c|}{1113}                \\ \hline
    \textbf{GossipCop}  & 3342                   & 2245                  & 
    \multicolumn{2}{c|}{1097}                \\ \hline
    \textbf{}           & \textbf{Total Users}   & \textbf{In Fake Only} & 
    \textbf{In Real Only} & \textbf{In Both} \\ \hline
    \textbf{PolitiFact} & 3865                   & 2763                  & 1081                  & 10               \\ \hline
    \textbf{GossipCop}  & 2564                   & 1706                  & 858                   & 8                \\ \hline
    \textbf{}           & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}} \textbf{1st Degree}\\\textbf{Fake Followers}\end{tabular}   & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}} 
        \textbf{1st Degree}\\\textbf{Fake Followings}\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}} \textbf{1st Degree} \\\textbf{Real Followers}\end{tabular} & 
    \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}\textbf{1st Degree}\\\textbf{ Real Followings}\end{tabular} \\ \hline
    \textbf{PolitiFact} & 312M                   & 27M                  & 534M                   & 19M               \\ \hline
    \textbf{GossipCop}  & 209M                   & 19M                  & 378M                   & 12M                \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table} 

\EOD  %<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< needed for ieeeaccess

\end{document}
```

Using  `\filelist`

```
*File List*

ieeeaccess.cls    
IEEEtran.cls    2015/08/26 V1.8b by Michael Shell
  ot1ptm.fd    2001/06/04 font definitions for OT1/ptm.
   ifpdf.sty    2019/10/25 v3.4 ifpdf legacy package. Use iftex instead.
   iftex.sty    2020/03/06 v1.0d TeX engine tests
 xkeyval.sty    2020/11/20 v2.8 package option processing (HA)
 xkeyval.tex    2014/12/03 v2.7a key=value parser (HA)
   color.sty    2020/02/24 v1.2b Standard LaTeX Color (DPC)
   color.cfg    2016/01/02 v1.6 sample color configuration
  pdftex.def    2020/10/05 v1.2a Graphics/color driver for pdftex
spotcolor.sty    2006/11/15 v1.2 Package for adding Spot Color support to pdfLa
TeX.
graphics.sty    2020/08/30 v1.4c Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
    trig.sty    2016/01/03 v1.10 sin cos tan (DPC)
graphics.cfg    2016/06/04 v1.11 sample graphics configuration
graphicx.sty    2020/09/09 v1.2b Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
multirow.sty    2021/03/15 v2.8 Span multiple rows of a table
l3backend-pdftex.def    2021-03-18 L3 backend support: PDF output (pdfTeX)
   t1ptm.fd    2001/06/04 font definitions for T1/ptm.
supp-pdf.mkii
epstopdf-base.sty    2020-01-24 v2.11 Base part for package epstopdf
epstopdf-sys.cfg    2021/03/18 v2.0 Configuration of epstopdf for MiKTeX
   t1phv.fd    2020/03/25 scalable font definitions for T1/phv.
  bullet.png    Graphic file (type png)
notaglineLogo.png    Graphic file (type png)
 ***********
```

Using MiKTex

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.22 (MiKTeX 21.3) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2021.4.2)  1 MAY 2021 11:37
entering extended mode
**./ieee_v3.tex
(ieee_v3.tex
LaTeX2e <2020-10-01> patch level 4
L3 programming layer <2021-02-18> (ieeeaccess.cls (IEEEtran.cls
Document Class: IEEEtran 2015/08/26 V1.8b by Michael Shell
```

Comment: With your code, I have the errors indicated by the OP (even though I have the expected PDF when going go despite the errors).

Comment: @F. Pantigny Funny. I added the output of `\listfiles`. I only get  warnings

 `pdfTeX warning: pdflatex.exe (file t1-times.map): cannot open font map file`


`pdfTeX warning: pdflatex.exe (file t1-formata.map): cannot open font map file`


`pdfTeX warning: pdflatex.exe (file t1-giovannistd.map): cannot open font map file`

`LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape T1/ptm/n/n' undefined`

but finish compilation without  reporting any errors.

Comment: Maybe you have not the same version of the file `ieeeaccess.cls`. I have just download mine on `https://template-selector.ieee.org/secure/templateSelector/publicationType`. However, it seems that there is no version number on that file. That's a problem.